# how can I resolve circular dependency between variadic templates in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, cyclic-dependency

I'm practicing template programming in C++, trying to implement some kind of parser library for educational purposes using only templates.

an example of how my library is supposed to be used is :

```
std::stringstream ss { "identif1er 123123 hell0 world 3rror" };

// zM = zero or more , aO = any of

using Identifier = Matcher<Alpha, zM<AlphaNum>>;
using Number = Matcher<Digit, zM<Digit>>; 

Matcher<aO<Identifier, Number>> numberOrIdentifier;

while(!ss.eof()) {
    if(ss.peek() == ' ') ss.ignore(1);

    if(numberLetters.s_match(ss)) {
        std::cout << "Token: " << (*numberLetters.val) << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Error\n";
    }
}
```

this is working, but I encountered with the problem that sometimes ill have to define a pair of types that depends on the other and vise versa.

I just want to know how i can do for example this:

```
using Expr = Matcher<..... Factor ....>
using Factor = Matcher<aO<Number, Expr>>;
```

How can i do a forward declaration of Factor using only types and no constructor arguments? its posible?, 
note: im using a empty struct "Self" to tag the recursion.

Link to the definition of the templates :

[templates code](https://gist.github.com/aindigo/14f0644dea6af9c720a60ff7b5ffdce2)

Comment: This can't be possible for the following reason: Fundamentally, these are only aliases, so they have to expand to a type without aliases. What should this type be? If you simplyfy your example to `using Expr = Matcher<Factor>; using Factor = Matcher<a0<Number, Expr>>;` the resulting type would need to look like `using Expr = Matcher<a0<Number, Matcher<a0<Number, Matcher <a0, Number, Matcher<a0<Number, Matcher <a0<...` without ever terminating.

Comment: So to get this to work, you need to implement some form of compile time simplification, in this case for the rule that `Expr ::= Number | Expr` is equivalent to `Expr ::= Number`.